# Running in an Infinite Loop C

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, quicksort, singly-linked-list

Im running in an infinite loop and I dont know why. I tried to debugg my code without success. Maybe someone can help me to fix this.

```
void init_list(list* mylist)
{

  mylist->first = NULL;
  mylist->last = NULL;
}



void insert_list(list_element* le, list* mylist)
{

  if(mylist->first == NULL)
  {
    mylist->first = le;
    mylist->last = le;
    return;
  }

  mylist->last->next = le;
  mylist->last = le;
  //printf("Test");

  return;

}

void free_list(list* mylist)
{
    list_element* tmp = mylist->first;
    while(tmp->next != NULL)
    {
      free(mylist->first->password);
      free(mylist->first);
      tmp = tmp->next;
      mylist->first = tmp;
    }
}


void read_data(char* filename, list* mylist)
{
  FILE * file = fopen(filename,"r");

  char line[100];


  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
  {
    char * teile;
    int index;
    teile = strrchr(line, ' ');

    //printf("%s\n",teile);

    index = (int) (teile - line);

    //printf("%d\n",index);

    char password[index+1];

    strncpy(password, line, index);

    password[index] = '\0';

    //printf("%s\n",password);

    list_element * le = malloc(sizeof(list_element));
    le->password = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(password)+1));
    strncpy(le->password,password,(strlen(password)+1));
    le->next = NULL;
    int anzahl = atoi(teile);
    le->count = anzahl;

    //printf("%d %s\n", le->count, le->password);

    insert_list(le, mylist);

  }

  fclose(file);

}

list_element* partition( list* input, list* left, list* right )
{
    list_element * pivot = input->first;


    list_element * tmp;
    for (tmp = pivot->next; tmp != NULL; tmp= tmp->next)
    {
      if((tmp->count) < (pivot->count))
      {
        insert_list(tmp, left);
      }
      else
      {
        insert_list(tmp, right);
      }
    }  
    return pivot;
}

void qsort_list(list* mylist)
{
    list right;
    init_list(&right);
    list left;
    init_list(&left);
    list_element* pivot;

    if(mylist->first != mylist->last)
    {
      pivot = partition(mylist, &left, &right );
      qsort_list(&left);
      qsort_list(&right);


      if(left.first == NULL) 
      {
        mylist->first = pivot;
      } 
      else 
      {
        mylist->first = left.first;
        left.last->next = pivot;
      }
      if(right.first == NULL) 
      {
        pivot->next = right.first;
        mylist->last = pivot;
      } 
      else 
      {
        pivot->next = right.first;
        mylist->last = right.last;
      }     
    }
    return;

}

void print_list(list* mylist)
{
    list_element * current = mylist->first;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
      printf("%s %d \n", current->password, current->count);
      current = current->next;
    }
}
```

It Loops in the insert_list part. After being called from the read_data. It also only loops when the function gets called the last time.

```
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("USE: %s <Filename>\n",args[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    list mylist;
    init_list(&mylist);
    read_data(args[1],&mylist);
    qsort_list(&mylist);
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    print_list(&mylist);
    free_list(&mylist);
    return 0;
}

typedef struct list_element list_element;

struct list_element {
    char *password;
    int count;
    list_element* next;
};

typedef struct list list;

struct list {
    list_element* first;
    list_element* last;
};
```

Input is as following:

```
asdfgh 31554
snoopy1 15637
qwertyuiop 24372
```

Edit: Fixed the Input.
Edit2: Fixed the Code with the help of the comments. Now im running in a loop in my partition function.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is wrong

```
char password[index];
strncpy(password, line, index);
password[index] = '\0';
```

You allocate `index` number of characters, but overwrite outside the array with your last statement. You should allocate instead with

```
char password[index+1];
```

Comment: Sadly im still looping even with this.

Comment: yes, but you need to fix such an error first, in order for somebody to be able to find your bug. have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 3):

The function read_data has at least three serious bugs.

First of all you should check whether the file was open successfully.

Secondly you are writing beyond the array password using the index `index` because you did not reserve memory in the array for the terminating zero.

```
char password[index];

strncpy(password, line, index);

password[index] = '\0';
```

In this statement

```
le->password = password;
```

all elements of the list are assigned with a pointer to a local array that will not be alive after exiting the function.  You have to allocate dynamically memory for each data member `le->password`.

So the program in any case has undefined behavior.

The function `free_list`

```
void free_list(list* mylist)
{

    free(mylist->first);
    free(mylist);
}
```

does not free the all allocated memory.

Also you have a logical error in the design of your list. If you have a twp-sided linked-list then the function `insert_list` should append a new node to the tail of the list. Otherwise there is no great sense to have the tail node for a singly-linked list.

Comment: So in my understanding the free_list should look something like this:
```
void free_list(list* mylist)
{
    list_element* tmp = mylist->first;
    while(tmp->next != NULL)
    {
      free(mylist->first->password);
      free(mylist->first);
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    free(mylist);
}
```

Comment: and the password statement like this:

le->password = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(password)+1));
    strncpy(le->password,password,(strlen(password)+1));

Answer (score 1):

Here's a problem.  Take a closer look at your free_list function.

```
void free_list(list* mylist)
{
    list_element* tmp = mylist->first;
    while(tmp->next != NULL)
    {
      free(mylist->first->password);
      free(mylist->first);
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    free(mylist);
}
```

On the first time through the loop you set tmp = mylist->first, then you free mylist->first, then you try to get the 'next' pointer out of tmp.  Except the thing tmp pointed to is now gone, because you just freed it.

Comment: Actually you didn't fix it.   You need to set tmp = tmp->next *before* you do the freeing.